# How to configure Intellij code coverage for jar in library

Tags: java, intellij-idea, code-coverage

I am attempting to generate code coverage for a jar that is in my library. I have a suite of tests that uses this jar and I would like to see how much coverage I am getting with my test suite. In Intellij's run/configuration menu, even if I manually specify to include all the classes in the jar, ex. "com.my.jar.*", I get 0% code coverage. In Eclipse, I was able to easily select the jar, hit 'Coverage', and get accurate results. Has anyone else converting to Intellij from Eclipse experienced the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

I got stuck on this too - I was able to get it working in Eclipse instead of Idea